# What is the criteria for Account Suspension?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just came across a profile -

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/1035/zaubertrank

While i can see somethings inconsistent - inspite of having questions that are 10 upvotes, and only one question with -1, the rep is frozen to just 1.

And the account is suspended till 2026. Don't quite know why.

Also, it doesn't look like a horrible spamming kind of profile.

So what could be underlying reason? Just curious!

Answer (score 2):

One of his questions got down-voted, so he edited it to remove all question text, and instead pasted an inappropriate ASCII art. This particular suspension was triggered by a single case of behavior toward which Stack Exchange has a zero-tolerance policy.

Comment: In addition to what Phonon said, it was an unregistered account, and there generally is little value in treating them as registered users.